# Виртуальное окружение python3.6 через python2.7

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, venv, renpy

Работаю с движком RenPy, работающим на python 2.7. Для нужной мне библиотеки используется python3.x. Можно ли создать виртуальное окружение, в которое установить более новую версию, дабы там запускать нужную мне функцию?

Comment: Новую версию чего? Виртуальное окружение создавать - это рекомендуемый способ всегда. В общем непонятно в чём вопрос. Или вы из одного окружения хотите запускать другое? А нет этого RenPy для 3-го питона? Проще переехать на 3-й питон, 2-й уже официально не поддерживается.

Comment: Если совсем подробно, то делаю модификацию для Бесконечного лета, который дистрибутируется на RenPy с виртуальным окружением 2 питона. Хочу подключить библиотеку для Discord Rich Presence (Подробная активность в дискорде), но она только третьем питоном поддерживается. То есть, я хочу в виртуальном окружении 2-го сделать виртуальное окружение 3-го, и запускать там функционал.

Comment: Так как вы пишите - не получится. Вероятно, придется напрямую обращаться к API дискорда, либо переписать библиотеку с Python 3 на Python 2.

Comment: Ну или переходить на RenPy 8, он на Python 3 работает.